# Azure additional subscription

Tags: azure

Good day,

Can I ask, what if I subscribe to Azure with only Virtual Machines and Bandwidth.

- Is it possible to add / subscribe to other services like storage, CDN, etc. in the future?
- Is it possible to upgrade bandwidth? E.g. I subscribe 300GB for bandwidth and then upgrade it to 500GN later on?
- For an eCommerce site that wants to purchase VMs what should I subscribe aside from Virtual Machine and Bandwidth?

Your help is very much appreciated.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure provides several subscription [options](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/)

- *Pay-as-You-Go* - extremely flexible option with no up-front costs and no commitment period
- *6 / 12 - month contracts* (giving you discount) - time commitment contract with (some with up-front costs)

[image: Azure Offers]

Azure charges are split into several types:

- Charged per hour of usage - Cloud Services (including Cloud Website) and Virtual Machines
- Charged per gigabyte used - e.g. Azure Storage, SQL Database, Bandwidth, Content Delivery Network (CDN)
- Some services are also charged per transactions.

All pricing details can be found in [Azure Calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full).

> - Is it possible to add / subscribe to other services like storage, CDN, etc. in the future?

Yes. Charges for those services (i.e. storage or CDN) will be added to the subscription you chose when provision those service. And you can have several different subscriptions (e.g. one for all storage charges, one for Azure SQL etc.)

[image: Subscription Example]

> Is it possible to upgrade bandwidth? E.g. I subscribe 300GB for
>   bandwidth and then upgrade it to 500GB later on?

You do not have to do anything (i.e. upgrade) in order to use more bandwidth. All charges will be added to your subscription. If you have some prepaid plan, you need to check the plan details regarding [discount](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/) etc. For *Pay-as-You-Go* plan visit [Azure Calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full).

> For an eCommerce site that wants to purchase VMs what should I
>   subscribe aside from Virtual Machine and Bandwidth?

You just need to provision additional VM, which will be added to your subscription. As above, for prepaid plans, you need to check the plan details regarding [discount](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/) etc. 
For *Pay-as-You-Go* plan visit [Azure Calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full).

I would recommend reading carefully [Purchase Windows Azure, and save up to 32 percent](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/) page. It is not possible to provide all details to this answer as the prices (including discounts) and the plans change. So something which is accurate today may be obsolete tomorrow.

I hope that will help.